# In SVG, Can we formate text inside desc tag Ex : <desc>Hello <br> World</desc>

Tags: svg

I am facing issue in SVG. Inside Desc tag I want to show text in proper format.
Adding space, new line but below tags are not working inside desc tag

Comment: Text in `desc` tags is not rendered in the graphic. Where and how do you want to show this text?

Comment: *"An interesting feature of <desc> is that the element can contain markup content from other namespaces, particularly HTML."*

Bellamy-Royds, Amelia. Using SVG with CSS3 and HTML5 (p. 668). O'Reilly Media. Kindle Edition.